# Best way to set and get values of object in DOJO class

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a class which takes in an object

```
{ 
    a : "abc",
    b : { z: 'as' }
    c : 123
}
```

This class needs to provide getter and setter functions for the properties of the object.

What is the best way to do it?

Should I follow Java style and writer `getA/setA` / `getB/setB` functions, or can there be an easy function or Store which can do this ?

Comment: Error in `b "`, should be `b:`

Comment: check dstore(store) in combination with dmodel(gives you set/get - prop). both are on github (sitepen). but careful, its not really fast as native.

Answer (score 1):

Julian Fondren's is a good answer, specially as it applies to JS in general and not only to DOJO.

In case you need setup getter and setter for a `custom widget`, you should use methods `.get()` and `.set()` from `dijit/_widgetBase`, below an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/f8pejjy4/2/

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (declare, _WidgetBase) {
    var YourWidget = declare(_WidgetBase, {
        a: "",
        _setAAttr: function (value) {
            console.log("Sets value of a to " + value);
            // some custom logic here
            this._set('a', value);
        },
        _getAAttr:function(){
          // some custom logic here
          console.log("Return value");
          return this.a;
        },
    });

    var yourWidget = new YourWidget().placeAt(document.body);
    yourWidget.startup();


    yourWidget.set('a', 'another value');
    yourWidget.get('a');
});
```

Comment: `this._get('a')` is not a thing.  The default behavior for a widget getter would be to just `return this.a`.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro thanks for your comment I have edited my answer.

Comment: dojo has somthing called as dojo/Stateful. It provides this out of the box

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use getA/setA functions.

```
var x = {
  _a: "a",
  set a(x) { this._a = x },
  get a(x) { return this._a + "bc" },
  b: { z: "as" },
  get c() { return 123 }
}

console.log(x.a)
x.a = 'x'
console.log(x.a)
console.log(x.c)
x.c = 1
console.log(x.c)
```

Output:

```
abc
xbc
123
123
```

JavaScript's getters and setters have the advantage of working as an afterthought.  When you decide you need them, you can add them, and the code can remain the same that had accessed and set the members of the object.

If the fake-private `_a` is unacceptable, you can make it actually private by having the getter and setter functions close over it:

```
var x = (function() {
  var secret = 2
  return {
    get a() { return secret }
  }
})()
/* no way to access 'secret' here */
```